# i want to print number from 1 to n but after running this code, error "core dumped" occured

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to print number from 1 to n but after running this code, error "core dumped" occured. 
I know code works well if i change self to n but why not self ???

```
n = int(input("?"))

def again_book(self):
    if n > 0:
        again_book(self - 1)
    print(self)

again_book(n)
```

Comment: because `n` is never changed so it is always greater than 0

Comment: You should say `if self > 0:`

Comment: (a) `self` is not a good name for your own arguments (b) don't do iterative things  recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working because you are never changing the `n` variable. In your function you're checking if `n > 0` and it will always be

Here is a fix:

```py
n = int(input("?"))

def again_book(self):
    if self > 0:
        again_book(self - 1)
    print(self)

again_book(n)
```

Another way of doing it is using a `while` loop:

```py
n = int(input("?"))
x = 0

while x < n:
    print(x)
    x += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

*I think you can use list comprehension*
[num for num in range(num_limit)]

Answer (score -1):

Self is used when you have to pass object itself.
[further you can read from here](https://www.programiz.com/article/python-self-why)